# How to declare variable outside the loop and set it to base value (float) in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this piece of code, I'm attempting to calculate the average of the person's scores as entered by the user.
Code :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    student_marks = {}
    for _ in range(n):
        name, *line = input().split()
        scores = list(map(float, line))
        student_marks[name] = scores
    query_name = input()

for i in name:
    if(query_name == i):
        sos = float(sum(scores))
        lengs = int(len(scores))
        avg = float(sos/lengs)

print('.2f'%avg)
```

Error shown in the compiler :

> **Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/tmp/submission/20220330/18/46/hackerrank-9395c8cfa7010e9d6e7964a4ac3c813/code/Solution.py", line 16, in module** 
>
> print('.2f'%avg)
> NameError: name 'avg' is not defined

Comment: That code is very bad indented. Also what is `for i in name` supposed to do ?

Comment: "How to declare variable outside the loop and set it to base value (float) in python?" - simply put `avg = 0.0` before the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for a second loop at all.  You have a dictionary indexed by `name`, so look up the `scores` you want to get by using `query_name` as a key:

```
student_marks = {}
for _ in range(int(input())):
    name, *line = input().split()
    scores = list(map(float, line))
    student_marks[name] = scores

query_name = input()
scores = student_marks[query_name]
print(f"{sum(scores)/len(scores):.2f}")
```

The loop `for i in name` was just iterating over the letters of `name`, which will just be whatever the last name you entered was; not at all useful for what you're trying to do.

Note that you also don't need any of the following:

- `if __name__ == '__main__'` - this is only useful if you're working with multiple files, and the way you were using it, half of the code was outside the `if` block anyway.
- `int(len(...))` -- `len` already returns an `int`, no need to convert it
- `float(sum(...))` -- `sum` of a list of `float`s is already going to be a `float`